# Understanding Field Notation

Tags: field-theory, notation

Can someone explain exactly what this notation ($\mathbb{F}_p$) means or point me to a link that comprehensively explains it?

Comment: Finite field with $p$ elements

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), the simplest examples of finite fields are the fields of prime order:

for each prime number $p$, the prime field of order $p$, which can be denoted $\mathbb {F} _{p} $,

may be constructed as the integers modulo $p$.

Comment: Some authors also use this notation while allowing $p$ to be any power of a prime (otherwise known as $\Bbb F_{p^n}$, if $p$ is required to be a prime). Note that in that case, the integers modulo $p$ does not work in general to construct the field.

Comment: Yes, @Arthur, there are finite fields of order $q$ where $q=p^k$,   $p$ is a prime number, and $k$ is a positive integer;  these can be denoted $\mathbb {F} _{q}$